# In iOS7 UITextField with secureTextEntry ruins layout in other text fields

Tags: ios, ios7, uitextfield

I am noticing very strange behavior of UITextField in iOS7 (works fine on < iOS7).

Easiest scenario to reproduce this bug:

- two textfields, one must have secureTextEntry set.
- the second (regular) textfield has Editing Did Begin hooked and does `self.text = @"something";`
- start editing the secure textfield and input a text using capital letters
- start editing the regular textfield

Suddenly the font and its placement will be broken like so (grayed - proper size/positioning):

[image: UITextField bug]

- if you play long enough and switch between the inputs, everything will randomly go back to normal and then break again.

I created a super-simple project that illustrates this:
https://github.com/jkrzemie/UITextFieldBug

Looking for a creative solution as this looks like an iOS7 bug...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... seconds later ...

Easiest solution is to be elegant and execute the `self.text = ...` logic in `-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` , it works flawlessly.

Comment: To make this more clear: Using the delegate in stead of IBActions did the trick. We should report this as a bug at Apple